Is there a 6:12 chart in Power BI?
Does anybody know if it's possible to create a chart such as below in Power BI? I don't think it's in the default options, but wondering if anyone has seen it on the marketplace?
Would prefer to avoid Python as it's still a bit slow in Power BI.
CY=current year, PY=previous year, WOW = week on week, YOY = year on year, YTD = year to date


Use Deneb and Vega.

Or you could fake it and have two visuals side by side, one for the 6 and the other for the 12, then show/hide y-axis as needed.
